# singular horizontal gradient across multiple <th> elements

Tags: html, css

Trying to create a table with rounded corners and a singular horizontal gradient that spans across multiple  elements. So far if I play the gradient to the row containing the table headers I lose the rounded corner. If I apply it to each table header element it does not span across all of them as if they were one which is what I am looking for.

```
<table id="roundTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="headerRow">
      <th id="topLeft">HEADER</th>
      <th>HEADER</th>
      <th id="topRight">SALE PRICE</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="tbody0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
      <td>
        test
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
th {
  font-family: americane, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #fe2646 0%, #921621 100%);

}

#topRight{
  border-top-right-radius: 25px; 
}

#topLeft{
  border-top-left-radius: 25px; 
}

#roundTable{
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the gradient to the row, and then with your selectors gave the border radius to the top left and top right.

```
#headerRow {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #fe2646 0%, #921621 100%);
}

#headerRow #topLeft {
  border-top-left-radius: 25px; 
}

#headerRow #topRight {
  border-top-right-radius: 25px; 
}

th {
  font-family: americane, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#roundTable{
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for me. Still getting hard corners in the header row.

Comment: This is not what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/qw39zvya/ This was the fiddle I did up with your HTML and the CSS I posted.

Comment: I want that but with the top corners rounded as well. For me the corners render with hard edges in the header in every browser.

Comment: the corners are rounded in my fiddle. Maybe try copying and pasting exactly what I posted?

Comment: I figured it out. It only renders rounded in chrome. Thanks for your help